# Openlayers - Problem with selecting features from overlapping vector layers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

I face the following problem.
I have two vector layers. One has linestring and the other point geometry.

When I add this line to my point geometry vector layer:

```
          pointLayer.setZIndex( 1001 );
```

I get the point layer on top and then I am unable to select any feature from the linestring vector layer.

How can I solve this problem so all the features are clickable? I wouldn't expect this behavior as the point vector layer just has some points.

Comment: Do you want to select features from only one layer, or both? How did you construct the selection control? Is it the `SelectFeature` control?

Comment: Yes. I need to select features from both layers. This is how I constructed the feature control for the linestring layer: wfsLinestringLayer.events.on({
      featureselected: function(event){.... For the point vector layer I want to add a feature.popup functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you have to look under the hood of the library. The `SelectFeature` control can be applied on a single layer or multiple layers.

- Single layer: The control's layer and handler properties receives the layer object, then you can select features from that layer.
- Multiple layers: The library creates a new `Vector.RootContainer` layer, which basically a vector layer group containing the layers. The control is then applied to that `RootContainer` layer.

This way if you modify the Z index of the original layer, you just block the mouse event from the created layer group. I have two ideas which would help you solve this problem in theory:

1. Get the `RootContainer` layer and modify its position to be on top. You can set the Z-index, but the more convenient way is to use the map's `raiseLayer` function.
2. Define the `pointer-events` CSS property of your layers' DOM elements. You can set it to `none`, to get your mouse clicks fall through completely.